# Python chat application with sockets failed to print received messages

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, chat

Hello I have trouble implementing a python socket chat system for a multiplayer cli game I am building.

This is the server code related to that:

```
#Server
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

ipaddr = "127.0.0.1"
port = int(8888)

try:
  server.bind((ipaddr, port))
except socket.error as er:
  str(er)
server.listen(100)

def send_message(un, sn, msg, t):
    return json.dumps({
            "status": 200,
            "type": t,
            "data": {
              "username": un,
              "servername": sn,
              "message": msg
            }
          })


def broadcast(message, room, connection, t):
  if t == 0:
    try:
      connection.send(message.encode())
    except:
      connection.close()
      remove(connection)
  elif t == 1:
    for client in list_of_clients.keys():      
        try:
          print("just send", message)
          client.send(message.encode())
        except:
          client.close()
          remove(client)
def clientthread(conn):
  while True:
    try:
      msg = json.loads(conn.recv(4096).decode())
      if msg["type"] == "sendmessage":
        res = send_message(msg["data"]["username"],msg["data"]["servername"],msg["data"]["message"],msg["type"])
        broadcast(res, msg["data"]["servername"], conn, 1)
      else:
        remove(conn)
    except Exception as e:
      conn.close()
      remove(conn)
      return

while True:
  conn, addr = server.accept()
  start_new_thread(clientthread, (conn,))

conn.close()
server.close()
```

Client code:

```
#Client

def game_lobby(sn):
  game_lobby_template(sn)
  while started != 1:
    msg = ""
    while msg == "":
      msg = input()
      if msg != "leave":
        send_message(sn, msg)
      else:
        leave_game(sn)
  start_game(sn, 1)


def receive_from_server():
  global server,members,data
  while True:
    res = ""
    res = json.loads((server.recv(4096)).decode())
    if res["type"] == "sendmessage":
      if res["status"] == 200:
        reload_template(res,0)
        else:
          reload_template(res,0)

receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=receive_from_server)
receive_thread.start()

#Suppose I call game_lobby() so that game_lobby is running at the same time receive_from_server is running
```

My problem is that the loop inside receive_from_server despite running only gets the first response from the server and then doesn't return anything despite receiving information 100%
Does anyone know why? Is this a multithread problem? A socket problem? I searched it up and there is a chance that I need to read the state of the sockets to understand if they can receive information? *I do not fully understand the last one*

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: TCP is not message-based.  It is a *byte stream* and 1 send != 1 recv.  You must check the return values of `send` and `recv` to ensure you sent all the data (or use `sendall`) and received a complete message.  Buffer received data until you have a complete message.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Can you provide an example of what you are suggesting? How can I buffer received data until I have a complete message? I tried a solution but it didn't work effectively.

Comment: Here’s an example of the [last question I answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75858257/235698) using `socket.makefile()` to buffer data.

Comment: Here's [another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73071517/235698).

Comment: [Another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9968240/235698) that doesn't use `makefile`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I can't get any of them to work correctly. I don't see how any of these can help me

Comment: Then make a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue. Partial code doesn’t help me help you.